# re-render template in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new in vue.js .

So i'm trying to figure out how can I make data property value change in every click event.

So here's my HTML code

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-slice-<?php echo $slice_name; ?>">
            <div class="slice-type-area slice-type-<?php echo $slice_name; ?> slice-type-<?php echo $slice_name; ?>-{{ slice_count }} p-3 mb-3">
                <div class="slice-top">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">{{ slice_title }}</h5>
                        <div class="ml-auto">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning rounded-circle btn-sm remove-slice" data-remove=".slice-type-<?php echo $slice_name; ?>-{{ slice_count }}"><i class="fas fa-times fa-sm"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="my-3"></div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="slice[{{ slice_type }}][{{ slice_count }}][title]" class="form-control rounded-0"/>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="tinymce-area" id="tinymce-{{ slice_type }}-desc-{{ slice_count }}" name="slice[{{ slice_type }}][{{ slice_count }}][desc]"></textarea>
                </div>
                ?>
            </div>
</script>
```

And this my js code

```
$(document).on("click", ".add-slice", function(e) {
  var t = $(this);
  var slice_title = t.data("title");
  var slice_type = t.data("type");
  var slice_count = $(".slice-type-" + slice_type + "").length;

  slice_count += 1;
  console.log(slice_count);
  var slice = new Vue({
    el: '#tmpl-slice-' + slice_type + '',
    data: {
      slice_title: slice_count,
      slice_type: slice_type,
      slice_count: slice_count
    },
  });

  $("#get_slices").prepend($("#tmpl-slice-" + slice_type + "").html());
  // Apply tinymce Editor to textarea elements
  tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "tinymce-" + slice_type + "-desc-");

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

So my problem is is var `slice_count` should add 1 to the results got from count slice type element but when render the value not changed always be 1 first value got from first render

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused here. Are you not passing props to the component? If so, it should rerender automatically when the slice_count prop changes.

Comment: @Marcus yes that what should be. but vue render template with first data props given

Comment: Do not use jQuery with Vue. Use [Vue's data and methods](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data).

Comment: @MouradKaroudi the way you're coding, vuejs can't monitor slice_count change. you must write using a different approach. Is .add-slice a tinyMCE element? or Is it a element you have added somewhere else? if it is something you have created you probably should write something like this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: Don't use jQuery with vueJS, use elementUI or iview for better rendering of a DOM.

Comment: u can use scoped slots ? <slots></slot> of vuejs2

Answer (score 1):

Each time you clicking the button you are creating new Vue instance & rewriting existing DOM element programmatically but your DOM element is not re-rendering because reactivity works for vue instance if you keep vue instance out of that click event.
this practice works for jQuery but not in Vue instance.

Vue using virtual DOM management for re-rendering.
Better I suggest avoid jQuery, Vue smart enough to work in two-way binding for its prop in html.

If you want to develop your code in vue then you must follow below link.its very easy & organized for beginners.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/

https://012.vuejs.org/guide/

you can start your app
https://medium.com/@BMatt92656920/getting-started-with-vue-webpack-bootstrap-fb69b24e6f3d

you can get lots of UI stuff here
https://madewithvuejs.com/